# Connecting to ReadOnly Secondary Replica of SQL Server via the Listener by Default

Tags: sql-server-2014, listener

We have the ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly properly routing our users to the Secondary ReadOnly replica.  Is there a way to make this the default behavior?

Apparently the default behavior seems to be ReadWrite, and if you don't specify an ApplicationIntent it will redirect to the Primary server.

Comment: The listener is just an IP and DNS name. You can't specify application intent

Comment: @AMtwo I might be getting the terminology wrong.  We have a `DB01` (active) & `DB02` (passive) that are synced together.  Then we have `DB03` which currently gets replication from the active database (in this case `DB01`).   When we connect to `DB_Listener` without specifying an ApplicationIntent we will be sent to `DB01`.  When we specify ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly we get sent to `DB03`.  That is currently working now.  I want to default to getting only readonly to `DB03`.

Comment: I added a full answer with some more detail--hopefully that answers your question. I'd also steer away from referring to servers as "active" or "passive".... They're trigger words for some people.  Primary/Secondary seem to be more universally used.  =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Availability Group Listener is (per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover)), simply "a Domain Name System (DNS) listener name, listener port designation, and one or more IP addresses." It becomes a resource in the Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC), and is used for routing traffic to the appropriate Availability Group (AG) node. However, it is ultimately just a DNS Name and IP.

When you connect to the Listener, it will *always* route to the primary (read/write) replica. The *only* way to have traffic routed to a secondary (read-only) replica is to *explicitly* specify `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`. There is no way to change the default behavior on the Listener to route traffic to a read-only secondary without specifying `ApplicationIntent`.

If you want users to connect to a read-only replica without explicitly specifying the `ApplicationIntent`, then those users would need to connect directly to the secondary server.
Note that if the user connects directly to the secondary server, a failover could result in that server becoming primary, and thus, no longer read-only.

In your scenario, if you have automatic failover between DB01 & DB02, and DB03 will "never" be primary, and you also want users to *always* connect to DB03, then you should simply direct users to connect directly to DB03.

However, if you want to take advantage of Read-Only routing so that the server names are obscured, and the specific secondary node to which a user is connected is transparent to them, then your only choice is to connect to the AG Listener, and specify `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`.